# Unable to deploy Cloud Functions for Firebase. Getting error, How to solve it?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I just started by following 'Getting started' tutorial. My index.js file contains the code :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
// Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push it into the Realtime Database then send a response
  admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
});
```

> > [debug] Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_1892YPzPCgcquJf3\node_modules'
> >         at Error (native)
> >         at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:887:18)
> >         at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\sai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:355:25)
> >         at rmdirSync (C:\Users\sai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:333:7)
> >         at rimrafSync (C:\Users\sai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:303:9)
> >         at C:\Users\sai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:341:5
> >         at Array.forEach (native)
> >         at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\sai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:340:26)
> >         at rmdirSync (C:\Users\sai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:333:7)
> >         at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (C:\Users\sai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:303:9)
> >     [error]  [error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred. [info] i 
> >     functions: packaged functions (997 B) for uploading [debug] >>> HTTP
> >     REQUEST GET
> >     https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/staging.mingle-be3a8.appspot.com
> >     Wed Apr 05 2017 10:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: post your code to understand your problem.

Comment: I just started by following 'Getting started' tutorial. My index.js file code is added

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner or other process that might be touching your tmp directory?